# Magento 2 + Varnish - Product pages not updating when product is updated

Tags: full-page-cache, varnish, magento2.4.2

I have Varnish 6.4 set up with Magento 2.4.2 in Kubernetes, and can confirm it is set up correctly by the "x-magento-cache-debug HIT" header. However, when I update a product, the product page isn't updating, presumably it is serving the cached old product page. Is there something I have to set up in Magento to get it to inform Varnish when a product etc has updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [official documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/varnish/use-varnish-cache.html#configure-magento-to-purge-varnish), Varnish is purged automatically when you perform the below actions.

> Maintaining a store (for example, adding or editing categories,
> prices, products, and promotional pricing rules).

I guess you missed the steps **[Configure Magento to purge Varnish](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/varnish/use-varnish-cache.html#configure-magento-to-purge-varnish)**. If you missed this step, Magento cache clean/flush will fail to purge the cache from varnish. Run the below command, it will configure Magento to purge the Varnish cache.

```
php bin/magento setup:config:set --http-cache-hosts=varnish-host:varnish-port
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that out.

Comment: Thanks, this helped. I had already used this command yesterday, but it turns out that my purge requests were 405ing due to my VCL configuration, which I worked out by using:

varnishlog -g request -q 'ReqMethod eq "PURGE"'